# Экспорт БД на пк с помощью php скрипта

Tags: php

Необходимо сделать экспорт БД на пк, путем нажатия кнопки в личном кабинете. 
Пробовал сделать так:

```
<?php
    # Если кнопка нажата
    if( isset( $_POST['dump'] ) )
    {
 $hostname = "localhost";
$user = "1";
$password = "1";
$database = "1";

// Подключение к базе данных
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $password)
or die('Не удалось подключиться: ' . mysqli_error());

mysqli_select_db($mysqli,$database)
or die ('Не могу выбрать базу данных ' . mysqli_error());


// Определение формата файла
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');

// Имя файла
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your-file-name.csv');

// создать поток вывода файла
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// вывод заголовков столбцов
fputcsv($output, array('1 Столбец таблицы', '2 Столбец таблицы', '3 Столбец таблицы', '4 Столбец таблицы'));
$results = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM user');

// цикл по строкам, вывод их
while ($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) :

fputcsv($output, $results);

endwhile;

    }
?>







<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="dump" value="dump" />
</form>
```

Но получаю ошибки:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>/home//public_html/DB_dump.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>/home/public_html/DB_dump.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
```

Comment: Понимать что написано и открывать руководства вы, конечно же, не хотите?

Comment: @u_mulder я так понимаю первая ошибка говорит об ошибке подключения?

Comment: `mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli link, string query [, int resultmode] )` понимать нужно лучше. О божечки, функция принимает аж 3 аргумента, 2 из которых обязательны. А сколько аргументов в функцию вы передаёте в своём коде? Один. Ну и чего вы после этого хотите?

Comment: `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in` тут все написано. Что вы хотите от коммьюнити? Попробуйте хотя бы загуглить ошибку, а не лезть с банальщиной на so и отнимать чужое время